# Maximal consistent set. Decomposition lemma

Tags: logic

> Let $\Gamma$ be a maximal consistent set. Prove: $\varphi \lor \psi
>  \in \Gamma \iff \varphi \in \Gamma $ or $ \psi \in \Gamma$.
>
> Now define $V_{\Gamma}: Q \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ as follows:
>
> $V_{\Gamma}(p):= \cases{{1  \mbox{ if } p \in \Gamma} \\ 0 \mbox{ if }
>  p \notin \Gamma}$.
>
> Show that for every formula $\varphi$ we have: $\varphi \in \Gamma
>  \iff V_{\Gamma} \models \varphi$.

I'm at a loss here. Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look up the definition of $V_\Gamma \models \phi$, I think you will be able to come up with an answer for the second part yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer for the more difficult direction of the first part.  Suppose, toward a contradiction, that $\Gamma$ contains $\phi\lor\psi$ but contains neither $\phi$ nor $\psi$.  Since it doesn't contain $\phi$ but is maximal consistent, $\Gamma\cup\{\phi\}$ must be inconsistent.  So $\neg\phi$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$.  Similarly, so is $\neg\psi$.  But then so is $\neg(\phi\lor\psi)$ because that's a logical consequence of $\{\neg\phi,\neg\psi\}$.  But since $\phi\lor\psi$ is in $\Gamma$, this contradicts the assumption that $\Gamma$ is consistent.